# How ditinguish overload function with "move" and "const ref&"?

Tags: c++, move

guys.
Today, I write a template class with an inner class which has a std::map member.

```
template <class ElementType>
class Manager
{
public:
    size_t getElementIDInManager(ElementType* elem)const{
        return _innerMapper->getElementID(elem);
    }
    void registerElement(ElementType* elem){
        _innerMapper->register(elem);
    }
public:

class Mapper{
    size_t getElementID(ElementType* elem)const{
        // !!! compile error here !!!
        // doesnot find lvalue operator[]
        // maybe "std::map::operator[](const unsigned _int64&)"
        //      or "std::map::operator[](unsigned _int64&&)"
        return _mapper[elem->getID()]; // "elem->getID()" return size_t value

        // !!! even compile error if just call
        return _mapper[0]; 
    }
    void register(ElementType* elem){
        size_t size = _mapper.size();
        _mapper[elem->getID()] = size; // assume this doesnot exists before
    }
private:
    std::map<size_t, size_t> mapper;
}_innerMapper;
};
```

then, I compile error with code

```
class IDClass
{
public :
    size_t getID() {return 1;} // just for test
};
typedef Manager<IDClass> IDManager;
IDManager mgr;
IDClass id;
mgr->register(id);  // compile pass
mgr->getElementIDInManager(id);  // compile pass, see last piece of code for error info
```

Could anyone give me a hint?
How distinguish functions that are "const ref&" and "move&&" when I want to invoke functions?
Just like the std::map::operator[].

Comment: maybe, you can ask yourself, where did I define _mapper, I can see just mapper member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to overload resolution between `const&` and `&&`. The problem arises because your `getElementID` method is `const`:

```
size_t getElementID(ElementType* elem) const {
//                          notice here ^^^^
```

and, to surprise of many, `std::map`'s `operator[]` is *not `const`*. If the key is absent, the operator call will *emplace* that key with a default-initialised value. That's why it cannot be `const`.

However, declaring your `getElementID` as a `const` method means that it cannot call any *non-`const`* methods / operators of itself **and** of any *non-`mutable`* field. As you can see, `mapper` is not declared as `mutable`.

You can fix this by:

- not declaring `getElementID` as `const` (not recommended)
- not using `operator[]` - you can use `at()` instead, but be careful - in case of the absence of the key, `operator[]` inserts it, but `at()` will `throw` an `std::out_of_range` exception. You may want to enclose those calls in a `try-catch` blocks.

---

Also, I assume it's just a typo, but you are inconsistently referring to `mapper` and `_mapper`.